# OpenId get from provider user's password

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid

I have client application and provider application.

I am using grant type authorization code. And after getting access token, I'm requesting for user information but there are just:

```
 1. username 

 2. email 

 3. address
```

Is it possible to get user's password too? And is it secure?

Comment: The point of token is to not use password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible and would be *incredibly* insecure for users.

Imagine if signing into random sites with Facebook or Google gave them your full credentials. That would make everyone's accounts compromised and basically defeat the purpose of OAUTH.